# CanCanCan alias method for a controller

Tags: ruby, cancancan

In my application I have permissions set up like so for an admin:

```
can :read, Journey
can :destroy, Journey
can :update, Journey
```

And I have controllers like so:

```
class JourneyController < ApplicationController

  authorize_resource class: :journey

  def index; end

  def show; end

end

module Journeys
  class VoidJourneyController < ApplicationController

    authorize_resource class: :journey

    def show; end

    def destroy; end

  end
end
```

This is based on how DHH does his controllers: http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/

Now the issue I have is that because I have a show method inside the VoidJourney controller (this is to show the user some additional information as we talk to an API) it means a user who doesn't have permission to destroy a journey can access it because show is aliased to read and only the destroy is protected in that controller.

CanCanCan has the `alias_action` method, but that only allows aliasing a method to another for all controllers, not just one.

The only way I could think to handle this was to do:

```
def show
  authorize! :destroy, :journey
end
```

So that it checks that method against a different permission. But I'd like to avoid having to do that if possible.

Is it possible to alias a method in only one controller to another? And not alias for all controllers. Looking at the docs I can't see this.

Comment: Your issue is not really clear. From your ability, seems like you are giving all permissions on a Journey, therefore all actions are allowed. Do you need specific permissions on that controller?

Comment: @coorasse Yes that's correct.

Comment: Let me understand a bit better: the idea is that a user can invoke destroy only on void journeys? How is a void journey defined? Does it have a `void` attribute?